# Would it make sense to use Object.defineProperty to define constants in io.js modules?

Tags: node.js, io.js

For example the dns.js file:

```
exports.EOF = 'EOF';
exports.FILE = 'EFILE';
exports.NOMEM = 'ENOMEM';
```

Those can be overwritten, e.g.

```
var dns = require('dns');
dns.EOF = 3;
```

what about:

```
Object.defineProperty(module.exports, 'EOF',
  { value: 'EOF', enumerable: true});

Object.defineProperty(module.exports, 'EFILE',
  { value: 'EFILE', enumerable: true});
```

and so on. In such case, then:

```
 'use strict';
 var dns = require('./dns');
 dns.EOF = 3;

TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'EOF' of #<Object>
```

Comment: To me, this seems super opinion-based. Kind of just depends on how much you trust your users? To me at least, this seems like overprotection though.

Comment: Good point. I suppose you could simply use Object.freeze on your modules to make them totally immutable as well.

Comment: Why dont use the new `const`-Keyword like `const EOF = 'EOF'; exports.EOF = EOF;`?